# How to use "Used Disk Space Only" encryption in Windows 7

Tags: bitlocker

I'd like to know if Bitlocker's "Encrypt Used Space Only" feature in Windows 7 can be tuned to speed up the encryption process, for instance by tweaking the registry or adding services or packages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this was only added in Windows 8 BitLocker, but feel free to check for it on Windows 7. You need to edit Group Policy at Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → BitLocker Drive Encryption → Operating System Drive → Enforce Drive Encryption type on Operating System Drive. The options are:

- Allow User to Choose
- Full Encryption
- Used Space Encryption

This GPO is also available for Fixed Data Drives and Removable Drives.

Keep in mind it is recommended to always do full encryption.

Comment: "Keep in mind it is recommended to always do full encryption." Could you name the source?